# How to save battery power for every Linux system so that you could use your laptop longer without charging?

Tags: power-management, battery

I'm looking for a general solution for this problem.

Because I need to do the coding outside. Sometimes the outside env doesn't have power supply.

Answer (score 0):

#### Base Theory

1. Decrease cpu frequency
2. Turn off GPU
3. Turn off other devices when not used

#### For general Linux system

```bash
sudo apt install tlp
sudo systemctl enable tlp
sudo apt install powertop
sudo systemctl enable powertop
```

```bash
sudo apt install cpupower-gui
sudo cpupower-gui
# use cpupower-gui to change the cpu frequency to minimum value
```

#### For gnome (including ubuntu)

```bash
sudo apt install tlp
sudo systemctl enable tlp
sudo apt install powertop
sudo systemctl enable powertop
```

Install `cpu-power-manager` and change the cpu-frequency to a minimum value:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager

#### For PopOS

```bash
sudo apt install powertop
sudo systemctl enable powertop
```

Install `cpu-power-manager` and change the cpu-frequency to a minimum value:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager

From top-right-corner, from power-section, set graphics-mode to `compute-graphics` and power-strategy to `battery-life`

#### Refrences

- https://support.system76.com/articles/battery
- [https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/monitoring_and_managing_system_status_and_performance/managing-power-consumption-with-powertop_monitoring-and-managing-system-status-and-performance#:~:text=16.6.-,Optimizing%20power%20consumption,-To%20optimize%20power](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/monitoring_and_managing_system_status_and_performance/managing-power-consumption-with-powertop_monitoring-and-managing-system-status-and-performance#:%7E:text=16.6.-,Optimizing%20power%20consumption,-To%20optimize%20power)
- https://yingshaoxo.blogspot.com/2023/04/how-to-save-battery-power-for-every.html

Comment: AFAIK it's redundant to enable both powertop and tlp.